# transition from developmental stage to deployment stage

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've created a web enabled database using SQL Server 2005 to store the data in the DB(back-end) and MS Visual Studio 2008 web forms to access the data(front end)....

I've sucessfully simulated the process of accessing the data from SQL Server stored in my friend's laptop through my laptop using SQL SERVER AUTHENTICATION in MS VISUAL STUDIO 2008 through a LAN Wire....

Now as a part of my project i need to deploy it in a real world server so that it can be accessed by a remote client through Intranet web browser like IE....

i'm confused as to how to go about with this transition....like what should be the connection string in web.config???....please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string should point to your real world server address/IP, that is, where you app will be deployed. Simple as pie.

How the authentication will be performed is an option that you choose while developing your application. This can also be configured through the connection string with specific parameters.

For connection string samples, take a look at this site:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

For protection related stuff, I advise you to read this page:

[Protecting Connection Strings and Other Configuration Information](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/protecting-connection-strings-and-other-configuration-information-cs)

Comment: hasn't helped too much....m still fuzzy about a few things....like i have been told that we need to take 2 servers (1 for storing the DATA i.e back end and the other for storing the front end MS Visual Studio Web forms....)

Comment: I see... As you asked about the connection string... I just answered about that. Indeed, it's good to separate things in different servers only if you're going to have a lot of users accessing your application.